# How do I ensure that my Detail View Controller is always embedded in a UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a `UISplitViewController` that has a `preferredDisplayMode = .AllVisible` . [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27SA8.png) is how I have set up my storyboard, notice how the Detail View Controller is already embedded in a `UINavigationController`.

I execute the following method when a specific button is tapped in the `toolBar` of the Master View Controller:

```
@IBAction func entertainmentBarButtonItemTapped(sender: AnyObject) {    
        self.showDetailViewController(self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SearchViewController") as! SearchViewController, sender: sender)
}
```

Now this works fine on an iPhone in portrait mode, but in landscape mode on an iPhone 6+, I see no `navigationBar` for the Detail View Controller (the one just presented). This is not the behavior I desire. Note that the default Detail View Controller is embedded in a `UINavigationController`, so as you can imagine, it looks inconsistent when the `navigationBar` is suddenly missing.

So then I try the following instead:

```
@IBAction func entertainmentBarButtonItemTapped(sender: AnyObject) {    
        self.showDetailViewController(self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NavigationSearchViewController") as! NavigationSearchViewController, sender: sender)
}
```

Now I am replacing my Detail View Controller with the same VC as before, but it is instead embedded in a `UINavigationController`. The behavior works as expected on a 6+ in landscape mode, since it shows the navigationBar.

But in portrait mode, I see glitched behaviour, because now as the new VC is pushed to the stack, I see the `toolBar` disappear on the original Detail View Controller, causing a weird transition where clearly something didn't go right.

How can I properly use `showDetailViewController(..)` so that I always have my Detail View Controller embedded in a `UINavigationController` but without any odd transitions? I think this requires me to modify the UISplitViewController delegates, but I keep getting a 'Cannot push UINavigationController to stack.' error.

Edit:
The only delegate I modified:

```
func splitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondaryViewController secondaryViewController: UIViewController, ontoPrimaryViewController primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        //Since splitViewController!.showViewController changes secondaryViewController to no longer be a UINavigationController, this must first be checked for there to even be a BlankVC.
        if let secondaryNavController = secondaryViewController as? UINavigationController {
            if ((secondaryNavController.topViewController) != nil) {
                   return true
            }
            return false
    }
```

I currently see the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably your UISplitViewController delegate method

splitViewController:separateSecondaryViewControllerFromPrimaryViewController:

which you didn't show.

I suspect that it is returning the detailView controller rather than the navigation controller that contains it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, implement the delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.splitViewController.delegate = self;
    ...
}

#pragma mark - UISplitViewControllerDelegate

/* On iPhone 6 Plus:
        Portrait:   This method is called and YES is returned.
        Landscape:  This method is not called.
    On iPad Air
        Portrait:   This method is not called.
        Landscape:  This method is not called.
*/

- (BOOL)        splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController
     collapseSecondaryViewController:(UIViewController *)secondaryViewController
             ontoPrimaryViewController:(UIViewController *)primaryViewController
{
    if (self.masterNavController.topViewController)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Updated original post, I am not certain what masterNavController is in your context.